# laravel load candidates with given skills

Tags: php, html, laravel, search

In my website users can create candidates (one-many relation) and those candidates can have skills (many-many).

User model:

```
public function candidates() {
    return $this->hasMany(Candidate::class);
}
```

candidate model:

```
 public function skills() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Skill::class, 'candidate_skill', 'candidate_id', 'skill_id');
}
```

Skills model:

```
public function candidates() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Candidate::class, 'candidate_skill', 'candidate_id', 'skill_id')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

I already have an index page where an user can view ALL his made candidates

```
$candidates = Auth::user()->candidates;
```

on the edit page, skills can get synced to the candidate in question

```
  $candidate->skills()->sync(request()->skills);
```

and back to the index page it shows how many skills the candidates have

```
<td>{{count($candidate->skills)}}</td>
```

now, I need to make a search bar. My table already has one(dataTable) to search in the already loaded td's. But I need a search bar to search for candidates which have certain skills, say I want to search for candidates which are synced with 'css' and only show those in the table.

I read through the laravel docs and tried eager loading it:

```
$hasCss = $candidates->load(['skills' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('name', '=',  'css');
    }]);
```

but this just loaded all candidates with only the css skill displayed, even the candidates who dont have it. I want to only load candidates who have the skill and leave the others out.

How do I do this, I'm clueless :s

Comment: "I want to search for candidates which are synced with 'css' and only show those in the table." .. but then you say .. "but this just loaded all candidates and only showed the css skills, if they didnt have it they would just have no skills." ... Its confusing what you actually want ?  can you explain more ?

Comment: I want it to only load candidates which have the css skill. but what that eager load did was just load all candidates with just the css skill even if they dont even have it.

Comment: Thats very much laravel related. You should update your question with model relations of user/skills/candidates you have. It will help

Comment: I already did? user has many candidates, candidate has many skills.

added model functions to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [`whereHas(...)`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Current user's candidates that have CSS skill:

```
$withCss = Auth::user()->candidates()->whereHas('skills', function ($q) {
    $q->where('name', 'css');
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Skill Model, you have an error in your relationship definition. You wrote

```
public function candidates() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Candidate::class, 'candidate_skill', 'candidate_id', 'skill_id')
    ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Swap 'candidate_id' and 'skill_id'. The local foreign key always comes first.

```
public function candidates() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Candidate::class, 'candidate_skill', 'skill_id', 'candidate_id')
    ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Comment: oh, never ran into any errors, so not sure if it actually does anything but thanks anyway :3

Comment: Didn't run into errors yet... because you haven't try to get candidates through skills. Like when you want to get a skill with all candidate `$skill = Skill::with('candidates')->find(1);` that's where you would have received that error.